# Sum of the days between 3 columns

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I am currently working on DAX (powerpivot), I've calculated the days between different dates, however the dates in Blank as a result appear with 300.

When I tried to sum the days without considering those 300 (as a previous result) the output  is:

[image: OUTPUT]

the ideal output would be using excel formulas:

```
=SUMIF(A2:C2,"<>300",A2:C2)
```

---

```
300 300 300 0
300 1   2   3
1   22  300 23
2   300 3   5
```

I am using this formula as input in DAX, I know I am wrong, but can anybody help me

[image: Input]

```
=
IF (
    AND (
        GlobalMaterial_CaricamBrazil[DaysE1] = 300,
        OR (
            GlobalMaterial_CaricamBrazil[DaysE2] = 300,
            GlobalMaterial_CaricamBrazil[DaysE3] = 300
        )
    ),
    0,
    ( GlobalMaterial_CaricamBrazil[DaysE1] + 
      GlobalMaterial_CaricamBrazil[DaysE2] + 
      GlobalMaterial_CaricamBrazil[DaysE3] )
)
```

Comment: please put the formula as text and not a photo.  It is easier to copy paste test than a photo so we can test.

Comment: @ScottCraner, please find the formula.

Comment: You need to unpivot your data. DaysE1 etc should be data, not field names. Then it will be very easy to ignore "300".

Comment: @RADO, unfortunately I cannot unpivot that table due to i am working with more than 1million of data.

Comment: @RADO Thanks i will keep it in mind if I don't get another answer, because already tried this and my excel got broken

Comment: You don't have to materialise your data onto a worksheet. Close and Load To Data Model, not Table, then you can easily work with more than a million rows.